# flask render_template returning blank page with no errors

Tags: flask, html-templates

I'm working on my first flask server on ubuntu and everything works for serving simple text such as

```
@application.route("/")
def application(environ, start_response):
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
        return("hello world")
```

however when importing render_template, creating an adjacent templates folder with the html, and substituting in

```
    return render_template("page.html")
```

it returns a blank page with no errors. I've tested and anything can be put in as the argument in render_template() and still, no error or results. 
is there something wrong with my flask package or my code?

thanks,
steph

edit: changed the function from "application()" to mainPg(), return that mainPg(environ, start_response) requires two arguments

Comment: What's in your page.html?

Comment: Delete or rename `page.html`, will u get error now? Is debugging enable? how do u run the server?

Comment: @DarkSuniuM it can't be renamed to a file that doesn't exist or Flask will generate an Internal Server Error at runtime.

Comment: @Zenul_Abidin That was the point, exactly.